# Twitter Rest API with Rails to Display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, twitter, oauth

I have experience only in making small simple apps in PHP, Java and ASP.NET. I had no idea what GET, SET etc exactly are and what REST services are. To try to use the Twitter API, I did some reading and got to know (I might be wrong here, because this is what I THINK that I know..) that you can make a GET request like this one: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json

I just need guideline on how can I display ( of a specific account ) number of followers, retweets, tweets, follwing, how the long the account was created, etc by using Ruby on Rails. I am not asking you to give me bread, I'm asking you to tell me what should I do to learn to fish?

Would you please like to tell me where to start? Eitherway, I tried my examples and tutorials but sorry to say that none of them even worked to just authroize my page via twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest starting out with this online book:
[Ruby On Rails Tutorial - Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

This book covers everything you will need to know to get started including what REST services are and how to setup and install rails.

It might take a few days to go through the entire book but once you do you will know exactly what to do to make your app happen.

Comment: Would you please mention where he's using *twitter Rest Api* ?

Comment: The book I linked doesn't mention the Twitter Rest Api specifically. However by definition 'Rest' api's are RESTful. RESTfulness is defined by a set of standard principles. This means once you know what a RESTful service is and how to use a RESTful service, you will know how to use any RESTful service. Furthermore if you are set on using Rails for your task, accessing the twitter api will probably be easy. Processing the data will be the difficult part. There are many library's, or gems, that allow you to consume Twitter's api. [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).

Comment: If you read the book above you will gain a grasp on Rails fundamentals, understand RESTful services, gems, MVC, and so much more. At the end you will know exactly what you need to do to access and process data from the Twitter api.
Your task is a trivial one and your question arises from a lack of Rails fundamentals. I have provided you with one resource to address your gap in the fundamentals, to "teach you to fish". Also the books quite fun to read. And it covers testing.

Comment: I love you :)
Let me start this and yes, you're quite right :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [Twitter API](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) It helps simplify the process.

If you are just setting this up for a single account this part of the twitter docs is useful https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom

As other people will most likely stumble across this, here are my steps to setting up the twitter api for a single user in rails.

Follow twitter documentation above to set up authorization tokens

Gemfile
`gem 'twitter'`

Create a helper `twitter_helper.rb` using environment variables to store your keys

```
module TwitterHelper
  def self.get_client
    Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret = ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']
      config.access_token = ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN']
      config.access_token_secret = ENV['TOKEN_SECRET']
    end
  end

  def get_client
    TwitterHelper.client
  end
end
```

Then do something like

`client = TwitterHelper.get_client`
`client.friends.all`

to return all friends of the account set up.